# Python SpeechRecognition mutes other sounds

Tags: python, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, pyaudio, pyttsx

I don't know if SpeechRecognition or PyAudio is causing this, but when I run my voice assistant program, all the sounds on the computer are muted and I have to restart the application to turn the sound back on. How can I prevent this?

**My Code:**

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import pyjokes
import random

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty("rate", 190)

def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def take_command(lan="en-US"):
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Listening...")
            engine.say("I am listening.")
            engine.runAndWait()

            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice, language=lan)
            command = command.lower()
            if "alexa" in command:
                command = command.replace("alexa", "")
            return command
    except:
        return False

def time_format_control():
    #some code

def run_assistant():
    command = take_command()
    if not command:
        talk("I don't understand")
        return False

    if "play" in command:
        command = command.replace("play", "")
        print("Playing: " + command)
        talk("Playing" + command)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(command)

    #some elif stuff

    elif "bye" in command or "close the program" in command:
        print("bye")
        talk("bye")

    else:
        talk("I don't understand. Wait a second and say it again.")
        return False

while True:
    run_assistant()
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. This seems like a regular computer issue. This isn't exactly where this should be asked. Maybe try checking your speakers or audio output on the device?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with system sounds but when I run this script, all the app's sounds disappear from the sound list and don't come back until I restart the apps. This only happens when I run the script.